# Transformation $T:V \to W$ such that $N\subset \text{Null}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

- $\operatorname{dim}(V)=10$,
- $\operatorname{dim}(W)=7$,
- $\operatorname{dim}(N)=4$.

Then prove that there is a linear transformation $T: V \to W$ such that $N \subset \operatorname{Null}\;(T)$, and what would be the dimension of this set.

My attempts: I think we can use the Rank-Nullity theorem. It says that $$\text{dim}(\operatorname{Im}(T)) + \text{dim}\bigl(\operatorname{Null}\;(T)\bigr) = 10$$
but I can't proceed much. A detailed solution would be helpful.

Comment: So $N$ is a $4$-dimensional subspace of $V$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for something other than $T(v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I don't get you :(

Comment: The linear transformation $T(v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$ has $\operatorname{Null}(T) = V$ so $N \subset \operatorname{Null}(T)$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yeah i am not looking for this. This is trivial :)

Comment: So for what are you looking?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{n_1,\ldots,n_4\}$ be a basis for $N$ and extend this to a basis $\{n_1,\ldots,n_4,v_1,\ldots,v_6\}$ for $V$. Let $\{w_1,\ldots,w_7\}$ be a basis for $W$. Define $T:V \to W$ by $T(n_i) = 0$ for $1\leq i \leq 4$ and $T(v_i) = w_i$ if $1\leq i \leq 6$. Then extend $T$ be linearity. That is, every element $v \in V$ can be written as a linear combination 
$$
v = a_1 n_1 + \cdots + a_4 n_4 + a_5 v_1 + \cdots + a_{10} v_{10},
$$
so define
$$
T(v) = a_1 T(n_1) + \cdots + a_4 T(n_4) + a_5T(v_1)+ \cdots + a_{10} T(v_6).
$$
Then $T$ has the desired properties you seek. Note that $N = \mbox{Null}(T)$. You can make it a strict subset by sending one of the $v_i$ to zero as well.